# Can you save a variable in session?

Tags: plugin-development, session

Is there any way to save a variable in the Craft session inside a controller?

I'm running a cron job and I need to store a variable as a session for every run to see if a condition matches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Craft's [HttpSessionService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpSessionService) is a thin wrapper for PHP's global $_SESSION variable.

You can use:

```
craft()->httpSession->add($key, $value)
```

and:

```
craft()->httpSession->get($key)
```

to save and retrieve values from it.

Comment: Brad - How would you grab the key in a twig template?

Comment: We don't expose a `HttpSessionVariable` class where you'd be able to access that. Hit us up at support@buildwithcraft.com if you think you have a valid use-case where you think that'd be necessary from a template.

Comment: Gotcha. I actually got what I needed from setFlash instead of httpSession. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

And for those needing this for Craft 3...

**Set (previously called 'add'):**

```
Craft::$app->getSession()->set($key, $value);
```

**Get**

```
Craft::$app->getSession()->get($key);
```

Comment: If you need to unset/remove a particular session variable key:

**Remove**
Craft::$app->getSession()->remove($key);

[Here are the applicable Yii2 docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session).